# Upgrading a locked Android 4.4.2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, updates, bootloader, rom

I want to try to upgrade my Huawei Y560-U02 Android 4.4.2 to anything newer but it should at least be Android Lollipop.

I opened another thread in regards for this phone in order to get the firewall working on it but since that did not work I want to try to upgrade it properly.

I did not know the steps on how to do it properly and ended up causing some damage.
There is a lot of information and steps on the internet and that is what lead to having some issues now.
I have already backed up all the data that I need and ready to proceed.

So the Phone is Huawei Y56-U02 2015 Android 4.4.2 Kitkat. The phone is locked.

Because I did not know that phones need to be unlocked first it caused damage to my boot recovery mode. I can't access it anymore as it would just get stuck in that. Otherwise the phone is booting normally.

What I will need is to find a way to unlock it which I understand can be done if I unlock bootloader.

Please provide me with the best tips and steps to get this done.

I did try to use the built in Huawei updater but that just installed a different version of the same Rom.

Locked phone I mean locked ROM.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to flash the phone with SPD Upgrade tool and now all is back to normal.

The damage has been repaired.